# UIScrollView Isn't Scrolling

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Every time this question gets asked on SO (and elsewhere) the answer is "make sure the contentSize is larger than the view size, and set it in viewDidLoad!" Yes, I'm doing that, so what else could be the problem?

In my controller's loadView: I have these lines to set up my view:

```
descriptionView = [[DetailDescriptionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 60, 160, 180)];
descriptionScrollView = [[DetailDescriptionScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 180), 5, 5)];
[descriptionView addSubview:descriptionScrollView];
[self.view addSubview:descriptionView];
```

Then, in viewDidLoad, I have this code:

```
[descriptionScrollView setDescriptionText:@"<lots of text that will require scrolling>"];
NSUInteger contentHeight = <** calculations on the text to determine height **>
[descriptionScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(descriptionScrollView.frame.size.width, contentHeight)];
NSLog(@"ContentSize: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(descriptionScrollView.contentSize));
NSLog(@"DescriptionScrollView Size: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(descriptionScrollView.frame));
```

Those NSLogs confirm all should be fine:

```
ContentSize: {150, 330}
DescriptionScrollView Size: {{5, 5}, {150, 170}}
```

When it comes to doing the actual drawing of the text, I'm using Core Graphics in the scrollview's drawRect: method. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
CGRect descriptionTextBox = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, 20, self.frame.size.width - 10, 330);
[self.descriptionText drawInRect:descriptionTextBox withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kMediumFontName size:kFontSizeMicro]];
```

I think that covers what I'm trying to do. The scrolling just doesn't occur. Can anyone recommend a tactic to figure out what to try to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're drawing in the scrollview's draw rect; it needs to be in a subview of the scrollview.